# Change Collapsing toolbar menu icons color on scroll

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar, android-theme, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

How to create Toolbar like **Google trips** application Trip Screen  [Please check the image in the below link]. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZVnC.jpg ,

Before scroll toolbar menu icons will be in white colour. After scroll toolbar is collapsed menu icons will be changed to grey colour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change toolbar icons color on scroll, I used ToolbarColorizeHelper .[https://gist.github.com/chomi3/7e088760ef7bca10430e][1]

i added the addOnOffsetChangedListener to collapsing toolbar to observe the toolbar scroll offset. Below is the code I used to achieve the expected UI attached in the above question.

addOnOffsetChangedListener((appBarLayout, verticalOffset) -> {
            //Check if the view is collapsed

```
       if (scrollOffset <= toolbar.getHeight()) {
                ToolBarColourizer.colorizeToolbar(toolbar, Color.BLACK);             
        } else {
                ToolBarColourizer.colorizeToolbar(toolbar, Color.WHITE);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use library see this link, i have used it: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout
also check this link it may be useful : [How do you change the color of collapsing toolbar when it's collapsed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38700748/how-do-you-change-the-color-of-collapsing-toolbar-when-its-collapsed)

Comment: @Sanjay Thanks for your reply , I want to change the color of all views in toolbar. Currently , I am inflating menu_white.xml when toolbar is normal and inflating menu_black.xml  when toolbar is collapsed. Though I can achieve the effect I wanted. I am not happy with inflating two menus and duplicating menu icons (black and white resources). Looking for better approach.